# Time difference among end dates of first records to next record first dates

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How to find the dates difference in minutes among different columns levels as

```
No SourceID  RecordID  Start Date               End Date
1  1         1         2009-09-07 09:12:00.0000 2009-09-07 11:00:00.0000 
2  1         1         2009-09-07 11:19:00.0000 2009-09-07 12:12:00.0000  
3  1         1         2009-09-07 12:23:00.0000 2009-09-07 12:54:00.0000  
4  1         1         2009-09-07 13:49:00.0000 2009-09-07 14:45:00.0000
```

How to get the difference between EndDate of first record with Start Date of next record and the last record with NULL value.

here 
result needs get as

```
 SourceID  RecordID  Start Date               End Date                 DiffMin
 1         1         2009-09-07 09:12:00.0000 2009-09-07 11:00:00.0000 19 
 1         1         2009-09-07 11:19:00.0000 2009-09-07 12:12:00.0000 11 
 1         1         2009-09-07 12:23:00.0000 2009-09-07 12:54:00.0000 55 
 1         1         2009-09-07 13:49:00.0000 2009-09-07 14:45:00.0000 NULL
```

Thanks

Prav

Comment: When you say "first" and "next", which column is used to determine the order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  SourceId,RecordId,StartDate,EndDate
   , DATEDIFF(mi,a.EndDate,b.StartDate) DiffMin
FROM table a
LEFT JOIN table b ON A.no = B.no+1
```

Comment: Nope: OP wants diffs *between* rows, not *within* rows.

Comment: Shouldn't that be -1 rather than +1 to get the result he wants?

Comment: A.row = 1, B.row = 2 are joined, then i substact enddate of row=1 from startdate of row=2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SourceId,
       RecordId,
       StartDate,
       EndDate,
       DATEDIFF(mi,a.EndDate,b.StartDate) DiffMin
FROM table a
LEFT JOIN table b ON A.no = B.no-1
```

Comment: A.no = B.no -1 this is the correct answer,used as well as verified.